# What would be a good way for SE Careers to incorporate coding tests / challenges?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I am a huge fan of the current capabilities of the whole Stack Exchange ecosystem, and if a potential employer asks me for an online resume, I'll send them a link to my SE careers page.

Obviously, one thing SE does well is highlight knowledge that comes in question / answer form. SE Careers also does a good job of incorporating blog posts, public repos, and other interesting stuff outside the SE ecosystem.

But one thing it lacks (unless I'm just ignorant and haven't heard about it yet) is a way to include online test score profiles, like those at Code Eval or Hacker Rank.

I like that my Stack Exchange Career profile page has a pretty comprehensive collection of my professional online "presence" but with so many employers using coding tests as a gatekeeper, could it be a benefit to have hooks to those sites/services too? (I assume that SE would not want to create/host its own, since virtually all of the network is q&a only.)

Comment: Smarterer was my favorite skill testing site as it was user driven. Pluralsight bought and pretty much killed it. I would LOVE to see SO bring something back to life like that and have our skills directly in our profiles and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the idea. Realistically, it’s not on our roadmap so I wouldn’t expect it in the medium term.

That said, you might use one of the other sections.

For example, you might use “Certifications”, which just offers a couple of fields to describe it.

“Apps & Software” will actually go scrape a URL to try to form a summary. Might be usable in this case too, but maybe a stretch.